# Book Recommendation in Homological Algebra.

Tags: homological-algebra, book-recommendation

*I am attending a course in Homological Algebra this semester, in the following special topics. I know that there are similar posts, but in this post I specifically ask to recommend me a combination of well written books or notes, with plenty of worked examples in the following topics:*

- General Theory of Categories
- Adjoint Functors and Limits
- Abelian Categories
- Hom and Tensor Functors
- Projective and Injective Objects
- Cosets and Homology
- The long exact sequence in Homology
- Cone and quasi-isomorphisms
- Homotopy projective and injective resolution
- Derived Functors, $Ext^1$ and Extensions
- Homological dimensions
- The homotopy category is triangular
- Derived Categories and Derived Functors
- $Ext$ as set of morphisms in derived category
- Derived Equivalences

Also, in this course, the suggested bibliography is the following :

1. A. J. Berrick, Michael E. Keating, Categories and Modules with K-theory in view.
2. Sergei I. Gelfand, Yuri I. Manin: Methods of Homological Algebra.
3. Peter J. Hilton, Urs Stammbach: A Course in Homological Algebra.
4. Joseph J. Rotman: An Introduction to Homological Algebra.
5. Charles A. Weibel: An Introduction to Homological Algebra.

Could you please provide me some useful information about these books?

*Thank you in advance.*

Comment: Does the course not have a bibilography? Modern references are Weibel (be warry of errata), Hilton and Stammbach, Rotman (be wary of errata), and there's also Cartan and Eilenberg. There are also even more modern references when you approach derived categories, homotopy categories, which revolve around dg categories. Be sure to look at these eventually.

Comment: (Note: I think you mean "adjoint functors" and "quasi-isomorphisms". I've edited accordingly.)

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Thank you for your comment. Yes, indeed but I would like to learn new books and to find some useful information for the books I already have been suggested ( Also, thanks for the edit).

Comment: OK, you can begin by listing the books suggested. :)

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Ok, done! See the edit.

Comment: Great. I have not read the book of Berrick and Keating. My recommendation is you look at Rotman, H&S and Weibel, and be sure to pick the last editions. You will obtain useful information about the books by reading them: it is not really useful to have accounts of other people, since everyone has quite different experiences with them. I'm afraid your question too broad and opinion based to be suitable here. But you are always welcome to ask questions to arise when reading these books.

Comment: OK, I have to agree with you. But, this is my first touch with the subject, so I believe it's useful to learn from good references. And ok, it's q opinion based question, and that's why I tried to add some criteria in my question.

Comment: Wow, you already have a good bibliography. How about just going ahead and start reading?

Comment: @JasonPolak Thanks for your comment. Of course I ll start (probalby with Rotman). But I just want an opinion for these books.